# Web API 2 + MVC 5 Share Identity Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, owin, claims-based-identity

I have a web API and MVC5 sharing the same Identity Table. The Context belonging to the Web API:

```
public partial class CrestfineContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CrestfineContext():
        base("WelbeckDatabase", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").HasKey<Int32>(r => r.Id);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin").HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").HasKey(r => new{ r.IDNumber, r.UserName});
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User").HasKey<string>(r => r.UserName);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });/**/
    }
```

While the Context belonging to the Web app(MVC 5) is:

```
public partial class CrestfineContext : IdentityDbContext<UserLogin>
{
    public CrestfineContext()
        : base("name=WelbeckDatabase", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").HasKey<Int32>(r => r.Id);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin").HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        builder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("User").HasKey(r => new { r.IDNumber, r.UserName });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User").HasKey<string>(r => r.UserName);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    }
}
```

}

The are both running problem is when Signing in to the Web App(MVC):

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<CrestfineManager>();
var authManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

UserLogin user = await userManager.FindAsync(login_.Email, login_.Password);
```

returns a null... though the same user credentials can be used to login to the web API and the user will get authenticated

**EDIT**

My User Model for the Web API:

```
public partial class User : IdentityUser
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  public string LastName { get; set; }

  public string IDNumber { get; set; }

  public string Address { get; set; }

  public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
}
```

While the User Model in my MVC app:

```
public class UserLogin: IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have realised that i can't even select data from the IdentityUser table it returns null yet, there are users in the system a simple query :

```
  var usr = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == login_.Email).FirstOrDefault();
```

returns null. However, I can perform other tasks.

Comment: are they different applications or hosted in same iis application?

Comment: Hosted in the same IIS, same solution different projects

Comment: Running on different ports ofcourse

Comment: how are you registering the authentication

Comment: I register through the web api.. and using tokens authorize access for the MVC i was hoping to only allow Login's and use Cookie Sessions

Comment: i feel your problem can be in registering. You might want to add some of that code, maybe someone can help