# Can't read data from Identity Tables(OWIN)

Tags: c#, authentication, entity-framework-6, owin

[In Light to this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278382/web-api-2-mvc-5-share-identity-table), I've come to the realization that I can't read data off the Identity Tables. Simple queries like this:

```
  var user = usercontext.Users.Where(x => x.Username == Login_.Email).FirstorDefault();
```

return null.
Yet the same shared database indicates there's a registered user

[image]

Comment: Did you check the connectionstring? Does the connectionstring in the config file match the connectionstring in the dbcontext class?

Comment: Yes they match. Since i can perform queries on other tables only the Identity User table fails to query